# python newspaper3k return a article_html by string, i want to delete matched string

Tags: python

Below is the code and output.

```
    article = Article(url,keep_article_html=True)
    article.download()
    article.parse()
    print(article.article_html)
        <div><p class="tt_adsense_top"> 


    </p>
<p> test test </p>
```

I want to delete this part from the string

```
        <div><p class="tt_adsense_top"> 


    </p>
 <p>
```

only leave

```
<p> test test </p>
```

when i use python re to match it, i can only match this line i don't know how to match blank line and blank space.

```
<div><p class="tt_adsense_top">
```

who can give me a example to delete it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'replace' function for python strings would be the easiest way. So for example you would do

```
a = "some string removethis"
a = a.replace("removethis", "")
```

You could also use 'remove' function, and the important distinction between that and replace is that 'remove' only removes the first string it finds while replace will replace all found substrings with the 2nd argument you pass to the function. I would advise reading the [python documentation on string methods](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) it has a lot interesting and important functions you can play around with.